# Align Text and Image vertically inside Row in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've got a `Row` with a star `Image` and some `Text` inside. I've been trying to make them align vertically whilst keeping the `Text` height flexible but they're always a bit off (see screenshot).

```
@Composable
fun MyRating() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.Green)
            .wrapContentSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        val text = buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(MyTheme.typography.bodyStrongS.toSpanStyle()) { append("4.0") }
            withStyle(MyTheme.typography.bodyS.toSpanStyle()) { append("/5") }
        }

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_star),
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red),
            modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .padding(start = 4.dp),
            text = text
        )
    }
}
```

This results in:

[image]

Notice the distance between the `Text` and the top of the star is smaller than between the `Text` and the bottom of the star.
Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Just use padding, and make your text bigger or your image smaller.

Comment: I don't get the same result when i try it inside Column with Modifier.fillMaxSize(), it fills whole screen because of `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` and i think it might be the culprit. You can remove it since you already align Text vertically inside your Column. And without it looks like `Text` is aligned correctly inside your Column when i try with default TextStyles

Answer (score -1):

Change your Image with this:

```
 Image(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Star,
       colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red),
       modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp),
       contentDescription = null
      )
```